# EE 2.6.1 relationships - just not working - at all

Tags: relationships

I don't know if I am just going a bit barmy but I upgraded a site we are developing from 2.5.5 to 2.6 and then to 2.6.1

Everything looked ok until I tried to make a playa relationship work and no matter what I tried there was no fun to be had.

I removed playa and tried to do the same thing using the new relationships field in 2.6.1 and still nothing.

The setup is:

- Parent Channel = schools
- Child Channel = people

  - Restricted to people with status of teacher
- Parent can only have one child

The code (which is on a page by itself):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="schools"}
<h3>{title}</h3>
<ul>
    {cf_schools_teacher}
        <li>{cf_schools_teacher:cf_people_first_name}</li>
    {/cf_schools_teacher}
</ul>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

In the output I only get the Schools title and the ul tags - I checked the database exp_relationships and the pointers all seem to be correct although there is no data in the field in exp_channel_data (i'm not sure if there's meant to be)

Am I missing something basic? Or should I abandon 2.6.1 and start again in 2.5.5

Many Thanks
Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it...

Because I am in the parent and there is only one child entry I don't need the cf_schools_teacher tag pair - just leave them out.

:)